# Relating the noisy data to it's associated original/actual one

Tags: data-privacy, differential-privacy

We have a set of query answers, i.e., $A = \{A_1, A_2, \dots, A_m\}$ and then we add noise to each of $A_i$ using a mechanism ($M$) providing differential privacy, i.e., $M(A_i) = O_i$. We denote the set of noisy query answers by $O = \{O_1, O_2, \dots, O_m\}$.

Let's say an adversary is given the sets $A$ and $O$ (in some shuffled order), and they need to correctly match up the pairs $(A_i, O_i)$. I want to compute the probability that an adversary can correctly match up each pair. Is there any mathematical formula to compute the probability based on our mechanism parameters?

For example, in the worst case where all $O_i$ are the same, then the adversary can match up each pair correctly with probability $1/m$. In the best case, where the noise is minimal, and the accuracy is very high, then the adversary can match up a pair correctly with a probability close to a hundred percent.

Comment: What does it mean for $O_i$ to be associated with $A_i$?

Comment: I meant with which probability someone can relate $O_i$  to $A_i$ from which $O_i$ is resulted.

Comment: More precisely, I want to compute the probability that an adversary can relate $O_i$ to $A_i$, from which $O_i$ is derived.

Comment: This can still mean many things. For example, you could say that some adversary is given the entire sets of $\{A_1,\dots, A_m\}$, $\{O_1,\dots, O_m\}$ (in some shuffled order), and they need to correctly match up the pairs $\{A_i, O_i\}$. You could say that the adversary is given correct mappings $\{(A_1,O_1),\dots, (A_{m-1}, O_{m-1})\}$, and then given $O_m$, and must exactly recover $A_m$. You could say the adversary has to approximately recover $A_m$. There are a ton of other options

Comment: I do not think your edits have clarified at all what you are asking.

Comment: I meant exactly the former case you mentioned, i.e., an adversary is given the entire sets $A$ and $O$ in a shuffled manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very generic and so only very generic principles can be described.

An simple example is when $A_i$ and $O_i$ are 1-dimensional values. In this case the best (maximum likelihood) strategy for an adversary is to sort both lists and then pair up the values according to their sorted positions. The noise model will provide a means to compute the [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) of the $O$-values conditioned on the $A$-values and by seeing where $A_i$ occurs in the sorted list one can compute the probability that the corresponding $O$-value is $O_i$.

For multi-dimensional data, the adversary's best strategy is to compute the most likely ensemble of errors corresponding to an assignment (or a greedy approximation thereto) and the probability of success is a Bayes factor calculation against other possible assignments and errors.

Comment: Given that our values are one dimensional and we have used Laplace distribution for adding noise, is there any other efficient methods than order statistics? Does order statistics work fine in this case?

Comment: To Daniel S: Could you explain how the noise model can help to compute the order statistics, given that, in our case, we use the Laplace distribution.